# How to sort strings where a string contains alpha numeric characters like ROLL-10 > ROLL-2

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

I want to sort my custom object where it has two fields. 1) Pincode(Long) and 2) Roll(Alphanumeric).
I wanted to sort Pincode as in natural ordering but when they are same, then I want to sort them by roll number in descending order.

I'm using Java 8 Comparators and I've the following code. 
Model:

```
public class AreaModel {

   public long pinCode;
   public String rollNo;

   public AreaModel(long pinCode, String rollNo) {
      super();
      this.pinCode = pinCode;
      this.rollNo = rollNo;
   }
   public long getPinCode() {
     return pinCode;
   }
   public void setPinCode(long pinCode) {
      this.pinCode = pinCode;
   }
   public String getRollNo() {
     return rollNo;
   }
   public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
      this.rollNo = rollNo;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "["+pinCode+" "+rollNo+"]";
   }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.javainuse.model.AreaModel;

public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<AreaModel> list = new ArrayList<AreaModel>();
    list.add(new AreaModel(535005, "2"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535006, "100"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535007, "30"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535005, "ROLE-45"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535005, "ROLE-10"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535005,"13"));
    list.add(new AreaModel(535005,"70"));
    
    Function<AreaModel, Long> retentionCodeSequence = AreaModel::getPinCode;
    Function<AreaModel, String> retentionDuration = AreaModel::getRollNo;

    // sort area by pincode, then by role 
    Comparator<AreaModel> lastThenFirst = Comparator.comparing(retentionCodeSequence).thenComparing(retentionDuration,Comparator.reverseOrder());

    list= list.stream().sorted(lastThenFirst).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println("***");
    System.out.println(list);
    
}
}
```

With that, the output what I'm getting is this

---

**[[535005 ROLE-45], [535005 ROLE-10], [535005 70], [535005 2], [535005 13], [535006 100], [535007 30]]**

And what I'm expecting is the following
**[[535005 70], [535005 ROLE-45], [535005 13], [535005 ROLE-10], [535005 2], [535006 100], [535007 30]]**

As you can see, even though pincodes have been sorted, roles haven't. And a role can contain whole number as a string or a number which is suffixed to a text.
How do I resolve it?

Edit: updated question with possible values in the string

Comment: You need to parse out the numeric part *as* a number and use that for comparison with a custom ```Comparator```

Comment: @g00se But the number is the part of the string which also contains alpha characters. How would I parse it?

Comment: Something like ```Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll(\\"D",""))```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the valid values of the property `rollNo` have the format `"PREFIX-DIGITS"`, i.e. it starts from an *optional prefix*, containing non-digit characters followed by a dash, and end with a mandatory numeric part, you construct a following *comparator*, which deals with *numeric* and *non-numeric* parts separately.

```
Comparator<AreaModel> lastThenFirst =
    Comparator.comparing(AreaModel::getPinCode)
        .thenComparing(Comparator
            .<AreaModel, String>comparing(area -> area.getRollNo().replaceAll("\\d", ""), Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .thenComparing(area -> Integer.parseInt(area.getRollNo().replaceAll("\\D","")), Comparator.reverseOrder())
        );
```

**Note** that when there are several instances of `AreaModel` having the same `pinCode` and one of them has no non-numeric part in its `rollNo` value, then this instance would be the last after sorting (*in a group having identical pin code*). If the opposite behavior is required, you can check this case separately by adding one more comparator to the chain:

```
Comparator<AreaModel> lastThenFirst =
    Comparator.comparing(AreaModel::getPinCode)
        .thenComparing(
            Comparator.<AreaModel, Boolean>comparing(area -> area.getRollNo().matches("\\d"))
                .thenComparing(area -> area.getRollNo().replaceAll("\\d", ""), Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .thenComparing(area -> Integer.parseInt(area.getRollNo().replaceAll("\\D", "")), Comparator.reverseOrder())
        );
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I've just updated the question. Could you please take a look. A string can contain a number as whole or it can be a suffix to alpha characters. How do approach in that case? Thanks again

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada Then which one should go first prefixed, or non-prefixed (`"ROLE-10"` or `"10"`) ? Prefixes might differ?

Comment: I've updated the question with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

As @g00se mentioned, the integer value in role should be parsed and used in the comparator.

Also, `ToLongFunction` could be used to handle `pinCode` and default `List::sort` should be used to sort current list.

```java
ToLongFunction<AreaModel> pinCode = AreaModel::getPinCode;
ToIntFunction<AreaModel> roleToInt = am -> Integer.parseInt(am.getRollNo().replaceAll("\\D", ""));
Comparator<AreaModel> byRoleDesc = Comparator.comparingInt(roleToInt).reversed();

// sort area by pincode, then by role
Comparator<AreaModel> byPinAndReversedRole = Comparator
        .comparingLong(pinCode)
        .thenComparing(byRoleDesc);

list.sort(byPinAndReversedRole);
// -> [[535005 70], [535005 ROLE-45], [535005 13], [535005 ROLE-10], [535005 2], [535006 100], [535007 30]]
```